# No traffic is going through the NAT table in iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I have added just some rules to LOG packets going through the OUTPUT chains, but nothing goes through the NAT table at all. It is clear from the counter of NAT table chains here (which the counters are zero):

```
sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [197:319667]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [178:12147]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [197:319667]
:INPUT ACCEPT [197:319667]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [178:12147]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [178:12147]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1491:3438016]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1687:231563]
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "SEP [filter-OUTPUT] "
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:test - [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "SEP [nat-OUTPUT] "
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 13 03:49:55 2024
```

Also i have enabled the ipv4 ip forwarding as following:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

But the issue exists yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that if there is no non-terminating target added in a chain, that chain won't run! The LOG target itself is non-terminating so the chains and the whole table won't run at all!
So after i added some terminating actions to the table, the logs got run and the counters started increasing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).